How to configure ModifyRequestBody filter in Spring Cloud Gateway using YAML?
I'm trying to configure the ModifyRequestBody filter in Spring Cloud Gateway using YAML, but I'm running into issues with the inClass and outClass parameters, leading to a ConverterNotFoundException. Additionally, I couldn't find any documentation on how to properly utilize this feature via YAML.
Configuration Example
Here's the YAML configuration I'm using:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: microservice
          uri: http://localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/books
          filters:
            - name: ModifyRequestBody
              args:
                rewriteFunction: "#{@myRewriteFunction}"
                inClass: "java.lang.String"
                outClass: "java.lang.String"

Error Message
When I send a request, I receive the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<?>]
Custom Rewrite Function
I have defined a custom rewrite function as follows:
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.RewriteFunction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

@Component
public class MyRewriteFunction implements RewriteFunction<String, String> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<String> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, String originalRequest) {
        String modifiedRequest = modifyRequest(originalRequest);
        return Mono.just(modifiedRequest);
    }

    private String modifyRequest(String originalRequest) {
        return originalRequest;
    }
}

Working Configuration with Bean Creation
The filter works correctly when configured programmatically using a bean, as shown below:
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, MyRewriteFunction myRewriteFunction) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("route_id", r -> r.path("/books")
                        .filters(f -> f.modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, myRewriteFunction::apply))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
                .build();
    }
}

Question
How can I properly configure the ModifyRequestBody filter in YAML to avoid this conversion issue? Are there specific types or formats that I should use for inClass and outClass? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

You can't add Java code is required
